# How is the user created in the default Users table of iCloud Dashboard?

Tags: swift, macos, icloud, cloudkit

I'm using the cloudkit, and I found in Apple's management platform, iCloud Dashboard, that PublicDatabse defaults to the "Users" table, and there was a record that should be my developer record.
I want to know how it was created because I now need to use the records under "Users".
If a new user opens my App, does it automatically create a "Users" record? Or do I need to manually create it myself?